# EWS: How to get created folder?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

For those well known folder we can use WellKnownFolderName.Inbox to get inbox folder, but for those created by users, how to set searchFilter to get them? I found that all user created folder has a common property that the FolderClass is null, but when I use SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.FolderClass, null); error happens. It says "Either the OtherPropertyDefinition or the Value properties must be set." Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var folders = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, 
    new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "name"), 
    new FolderView(1));
```

This will return the first folder named "name".

Comment: In this case, you have to know the name of the created folder.

Comment: I want to use loop to get all created folders, which I don't have to know their names.

Comment: To get all folders, just omit the SearchFilter and specify a larger value in the FolderView.